# Disallow editing of tables in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

What is the best way to disallow editing of existing entries in ASP.NET Dynamic Data while it should still be possible to add new entries? If possible, I would prefer a solution without custom templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution myself: http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/05/introduction-this-project-is-going-to.html